# Can't change row hight in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here's the file, I changed the row hight of the Table View Cell in the size inspector to 240, but it's still default size when it runs. 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73195660/Test%20Auto%20Layout.zip

Comment: you are amazing :) You can not post the whole project as zip and expect that someone will open it. Ok some people can do that, but this is not the idea of stackoverflow

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController or a normal UIViewController with a TableView in it?

Comment: You maybe did not delegate and dataSource the tableview, at first do it and try.

Comment: and then use the UITableView delegate methods.

Comment: dit thanks I'll try avoiding it in the future.

Comment: Johan I'm using a normal UIViewController with a TableView

Comment: Sabrina thanks I'm trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 240;
}
```

Put this in your UITableViewController. If you are using a stand-alone UITableView, first set the delegate in the viewDidLoad method of your viewController:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working in IB from version of iOS 7
For Objective-c define this method in your class

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
        return 80; //return height

}
```

for Swift define in class method

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80 //return height
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just go to the Main.StoryBoard.
Following image shows the steps for solve your problem.[image]

Comment: This is what I did in the file, and it didn't work out. Maybe it's because I didn't connect it with the delegate or something.

Comment: ofcause you need to connect delegate and datasource for fill the data into cell.